# TradingView Strategy ATR stop (MTF)

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am looking to incorporate a simple ATR stop into my strategy. The ATR is referencing a different resolution (60 minute). I require the ability to change the 'ATR Multiplier'.

```
atrlength = input(14, "ATR Length")
atrmultip = input(3, "ATR Multiplier")
atrresCustom = input(title="Custom Resolution", type=resolution, 
defval="60")
useatrCurrentRes = input(false, title="Use Current Resolution")
res = useatrCurrentRes ? period : atrresCustom
atr = atr(atrlength)
mtfatr = security(tickerid, res, atr)
atrstop = (mtfatr*atrmultip)
strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, when=buy_alert)
strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short, when=sell_alert)
strategy.exit("SL/TP", loss=atrstop, profit=atrstop)
```

This is a key part of my strategy and I need to have this prior to applying other parameters of my strategy.

The output of this code is positions being closed within the same candle of the setup.

Any idea's what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what are `sell_alert/buy_alert` ? For debugging you code you can plot values of `atrstop` and look at working of the strategy more careful. I'd advise change the strategy temporary to a regular script, and make plot(1) when `buy_alert/sell_alert` are true. And plot `atrstop`

Comment: The buy/sell_alert are the setups created from my strategy. The ATR stop section of the code (above) outputs the correct values when ran as a study script. If I plotted this as overlay (close) -+ atrstop then it would plot correctly. However when using the value alone with loss/profit in the strategy script it wasn't working for some reason.